# query with contains - time out expired

Tags: sql-server

I have this following query : ( the tweetentity table has got about 100,000 records)

```
 select top 1 * from tweetentity  WHERE contains( HashTag , '%23%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b3%d8%b9%d8%a7%d8%af%d9%87_%d8%a7%d8%b4%d9%88%d9%81%d9%87%d8%a7')
```

which runs in less than a second. (There are a total of 86 records for the query). But when I run this query,

```
select top 1 * from tweetentity  WHERE contains( HashTag , '%23%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b3%d8%b9%d8%a7%d8%af%d9%87_%d8%a7%d8%b4%d9%88%d9%81%d9%87%d8%a7')  ORDER by FavoriteCount DESC, LastModifiedDatetime desc
```

it times out.

I have the following index for this table, yet the time runs out.

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TweetEntity_FavoriteCount1] ON [dbo].[TweetEntity] 
 (
[FavoriteCount] DESC,
[LastModifiedDateTime] DESC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

Comment: Include HashTag into index?

Comment: Its full text indexed.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with fulltext indexes, this was just simple idea to check out. For ordinary indexes my suggestion would change query plan substantially - you can look (show execution plan in SSMS), what happens in your case. As compromise you could add where condition (`HashTag like '%....%'`) - this would benefit from suggested index, but of course fulltext index won't be used then.

Comment: Couple more ideas :) Drop/disable this index - will it make a difference? Use CTE with your `contains()` condition, returning ID and at least ordering fields, without any specific order and select top N from CTE, using `order by` - will that make a difference? You have data and tools, you can experiment with ideas - I can only speculate :)

Answer (score 1):

When you `select top n without sort` (`ORDER BY)`, `mssql` get only n first records (rows) correct codition (`WHERE`). Thus, `mssql` no need scan all records

Contrast, `select top with sort`, `mssql` scan all records, get records correct condition, then sort columns and get n columns

Index can help you faster scan, faster sort. Your index just help you faster sort! You can add columns included in where clause into your index (Note: make it leading key), like this:

```
CREATE INDEX Index_name ON Your_Table
(list columns in where clause, list columns in order by clause)
-- no need get all columns in per clause
```

Comment: What do you mean by leading key? do you mean primary key? should it be clustered or non clustered. Please advise

Comment: when you create index without clustered or non clustered, it's default non clustered. Leading key mean first column in index :)